# Why would one M1 machine need architecture-specific options for building from source and other M1 machines not?

Tags: make, macos, configure, autoconf

I have tool version managers in the Ruby and react-native worlds that (underneath the layers of abstraction) end up building software like Ruby from source using a fairly mundane:

```
./configure
./make
./make install
```

... with various options passed into those commands from the abstractions above.

On my M1 MacBook Pro I find I have to carefully pass in command line options to get the build to understand what architecture I am running. For instance:

`export CONFIGURE_OPTS="--build aarch64-apple-darwin20"; asdf install ruby 2.6.6`

...prevents configure from breaking during `asdf install` with an error like, `machine not recognised`.

Digging down I can see a `config.sub` file in the build directory that was created in 2007. It doesn't know anything about the arm64 architecture.

I am fairly certain that the problem is here because `./configure` succeeds if I substitute a 2021 version config.sub from another project and try again.

I am very surprised to find that colleagues who are installing the same software on M1 machines with the exact same `asdf install...` process do not have any such hassles.

This is not `asdf`-specific, I have the same problem with dependencies installed by CocoaPods, which is also underneath it all using `configure` and `make`, and similarly my colleagues do not have any problems.

Something on other people's machines (or mine) is overriding the results of config.sub, or must be giving them a different copy of config.sub. I am mystified.

Update: one significant difference between the "working" machines and mine seems to be the output of uname:

Mine:

```
Darwin 192.168.1.102 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:27 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64 arm64 MacBookPro17,1 Darwin
```

others':

```
Darwin Joes-MacBook-Pro.local 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
```

In particular `uname -p` reports `arm` on others' machines and `arm64` on mine.

Comment: What `uname` are you using? If it comes from coreutils, it might be this issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/71782